# How to create "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler" type dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I am trying to create dynamically a type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` in C#.

I try:

```
 var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

type is `System.Type` = `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler`

but this throw exception:

`System.NotSupportedException`: „Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler'. Reason: Cannot create boxed ByRef-like values.”

### Context

I get `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` from `methodInfo.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables` - this is the list of local method variables visible in IL:

[image: example IL instructions]

### High-level

I am trying to simulate/execute IL instructions for a method that has `$"Some text with {1} value"`.

For example method:

```
public string Start()
{
    int i = 4;
    var text = $"Some text with {i} value";
    return text;
}
```

IL version:
[image]

I have mostly everything done for the simulation, but I need somehow create this type `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler`.

I think is a challange because of: `[System.Runtime]` and `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`.

Comment: There is currently no support for ref structs in reflection -- the reflection APIs box everything to `object`, and ref structs cannot be boxed. [See here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/10057) for the tracking issue. You can workaround using compiled expressions, or System.Reflection.Emit

Comment: @canton7 Thx, You pointed me in the right direction. The "problem" is with `ref struct`  and "A ref struct can't be boxed to System.ValueType or System.Object.". I can create it by the expression but can't past to heap. checking  System.Reflection.Emit...

Comment: Source generators aren't an option for you?

Comment: I think @canton7's answer is the correct form of the question I asked, but for me the problem now is how to put somehow the `ref struct` on the heap and I think it is not possible. So I decided to avoid the problem :) and not use the `$"some text with {2}" construct.

Comment: You can't put a ref struct on the heap - that's the entire point of ref structs, unfortunately.

Comment: @canton7 I know (now), but my scenario is super specific and technical - I'm working on a virtual machine, that emulates IL instructions from method.. and in the VM I have my own stack (call and evaluation) and some time I need to create a `ref struct`.

Comment: Mono has an [IL interpreter](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/main/mono/mini/interp) -- it would be interesting to see how they implement this.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro it's an interesting idea, but in the end I need to have some way to pass `ref struct` as some kind of object (by ref). I think I need some low-level trick, mayby to force to create this as regular stuct. Mayby something similar like in debugger. But for now I'll be avoiding it. Thx